# Issue in converting Unix timestamp get from moment to normal date

Tags: momentjs, unix-timestamp

I am using `moment().valueOf()` to get unix timestamp and to get the normal time from unix time i'm using `moment.unix(unix_time).format('LLL')` when the unix value is `1606985226404` getting the anser as `May 2, 52893 6:36 AM` which is incorrect. What is the issue with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of Moment.JS, moment() works with milliseconds.

So:

```
const unix_time = moment().valueOf(); // return epoc in milliseconds
const now = moment.unix(unix_time / 1000).format('LLL').
```

That's the trick.